# How to use SharedPreferences to check if the user is using an app or not?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
   @Override
    public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    mDatabaseReference.child("Online").setValue(true);
    }

   @Override
    public void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    mDatabaseReference.child("Online").setValue(false);
    }
```

My current code doesn't do the job to see if the user is online or not and people told me that i could use shared preferences for achieving the objective but i'm not sure on how to use shared preferences for editing a database value... i had only used shared preferences to check if the user had passed through an activity to skip it the next time (Signup activity and activities similar which require only one time access)
Can someone please help me out on how to use shared preferences to check if the user is online or not

Comment: use quotes in  mDatabaseReference.child("Online").setValue("true");

Comment: That just turns boolean into a string... how is it related to shared preferences? i want to achieve that using shared preferences

Comment: What errors are you facing in current code ?

Comment: When i open an activity and when the on start runs it shows online in the database and when i proceed to the next activity it shows online again and the next second turns offline because the on stop of the previous activity will be executed last... i want to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code. It worked fine in my case

```
@Override
protected void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();

    currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

    if (currentUser == null)
    {
        LogOutUser();
    }
    else if(currentUser != null)
    {
        UsersReference.child("online").setValue("true");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use `SharedPreferences` in such case. A simple way in which you can achieve this would be to use your `Online` property for each user in your database to see if it is or not online. For this, I recommend you to use Firebase's built-in `onDisconnect()` method. It enables you to predefine an operation that will happen as soon as the client becomes `disconnected`.

See [Firebase documentation for presence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-presence).

You can also can detect the connection state of the user. For many presence-related features, it is useful for your app to know when it is `online` or `offline`. Firebase Realtime Database provides a special location at:

```
/.info/connected`
```

Which is updated every time the Firebase realtime Database client's connection state changes. Here is an example also from the official documentation:

```
DatabaseReference connectedRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(".info/connected");
    connectedRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            boolean connected = snapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);
            if (connected) {
                System.out.println("connected");
            } else {
                System.out.println("not connected");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            System.err.println("Listener was cancelled");
        }
});
```

Comment: Is there everything alright, can I help you with other informations?